# Print from Scratch as it looks in the editor

Tags: release-loki, code

How do I print (to a file) from Scratch editor as it looks (mono-scpaced and syntax highlighted)?

Comment: You might want to file a wishlist bug on this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+filebug

Comment: Actually, I was thinking if there's already an extension or such, so I posted it here. Thanks, I'll file a wishlist bug.